# IControllerFactory did not return a controller for the name 'Handlers' using HTTP Handler to call Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, httphandler

Am working on a asp.net MVC application.

On a button Click am having an JQUERY AJAX call and am calling the handler ProcessRequest function.

From that function am calling a function inside a controller(Loading JQUERY DataTable Dynamically am doing this way with handler first). Everything works fine in my local machine

But when i deploy in IIS am getting

```
"The IControllerFactory '.....Web.ControllerFactory' did not return a controller for the name 'Handlers'"
```

Is this something to do with registering routes  ?

What is the issue...What am missing here?

Comment: You are probably missing a handler configuration in your web.config. Since there's no handler defined, your MVC kicks in and tries to map the request to a controller, which fails. Also in your route configuration it's best to call IgnoreRoute for the specific handler.

Comment: i have registered in my web.config. how do i add or ignore in my route configuration ?

Comment: you can call `.IgnoreRoute("/url/for/your/handler")`

Comment: am confused on how it works locally but not in IIS ?

Comment: it probably runs from visual studio or CLI engine from the framework but not after it deploys to IIS. I am down a similar rabbit hole and landed on this page.